# google charts change total number in Y axis

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I have a chart like so

[image]

What I am trying to do is change the total number on top which is `1,000` to a higher number. I can't figure out what the `options` value I need to make that change.

```
    var options = {
        title: 'This is my title',
        curveType: 'function',
        legend: { position: 'bottom' }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `viewWindow` option for `vAxis` (vertical axis)...

```
    vAxis: {
      viewWindow: {
        max: 2000  // <-- set maximum number
      }
    }
```

you can also set the `min`, if needed...

```
    vAxis: {
      viewWindow: {
        min: 0,
        max: 2000
      }
    }
```

e.g.

```
var options = {
    title: 'This is my title',
    curveType: 'function',
    legend: { position: 'bottom' },
    vAxis: {
      viewWindow: {
        max: 2000
      }
    }
};
```